# accessing Excelfile from Resources

Tags: c#

i am trying to access a Excel file stored in my Resources and build-embed by OLEDB but when i run the program i get database is read only.. i am using the below code. Please help

conMap.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +                   CTARepository.Properties.Resources.mapping + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                conMap.Open();

mapping is my mapping.xls file

Comment: What do you mean by "Resources" - do you mean embedded resource? (i.e. what does `CTARepository.Properties.Resources.mapping` equal?)

Comment: hi paul..
yes it is a embedded resource

Comment: You might need to flesh out the question if the link below (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746782/accessing-an-excel-resource-in-another-c-project) does not answer the question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get some idea from [Accessing an excel resource in another c# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746782/accessing-an-excel-resource-in-another-c-project)